# Putting all numbers in a string into an array

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a string like this: `1-4,9-12`.Is there some way I can get an array that contains this:`[1,4,9,12]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
"1-4,9-12".match(/\d+/g) // ["1", "4", "9", "12"]
```

The regular expression `\d+` matches any sequence of one or more decimal digits. The global (`g`) flag ensures that all matches are captured into the result array.

The result array will contain strings. If you want to parse these numbers, you can use the [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) function (or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)) with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)* like this:

```
"1-4,9-12".match(/\d+/g).map(Number) // [1, 4, 9, 12]
```

* `map` requires a browser that supports ECMAScript 5.1 or later. For older browsers, either polyfill the method (see the MDN article for an example), use a library that has a similar function such as [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) or [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#map), or use a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

in javascript:

```
var string = "1-4,9-12";
    string = string.replace(/-/g, ',');
var arr = string.split(',');   //arr is the array that you need.
```

Comment: Not working perfectly. the out put of your code is - ["1", "4", "9-12"]